# How to show multiple drawn polygons in Mapbox

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js, turfjs

I want to make an interactive map, where the use can create a polygon (area) and save it. The user should be able to see all the created areas. So I need to render the multiPolygon with the coordinates given by the server, and also allow the user to add more.

This is my code:

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
    center: coords,
});
var draw = new MapboxDraw({
    displayControlsDefault: false,
    controls: {
        polygon: true,
        trash: true
    }
});

map.addControl(draw);

map.on('load', function () {
    var multiPolygon = turf.multiPolygon([[pol1],[pol2],[pol3]]);
    // How to render multiPolygon??
});

map.on('draw.create', function (e) {
    const coords = e.features[0].geometry.coordinates;

    // Here save the coords as a new polygon
});
```

But I'm not able to make this code works! Can someone help me, please??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I did it adding each polygon individually:

```
// I get areas var from server, which is an array of coordinates
map.on('load', function () {
    map.resize();
    if (areas.length) {
        areas.forEach(area => draw.add(turf.polygon(area.polygon, { id_area: area.id_area, name: area.name })));
    }
});
```